Reading XML in Velo JS Backend: Error: Converting circular structure to JSON
I am trying to fetch a XML document in Wix Velo JS Backend, but I have the: “Error: Converting circular structure to JSON”.
I use the following code to read the XML:
export const get_branches_func = webMethod(Permissions.Anyone, (token) =>  
{
 ....
  return fetch('https://webservices.vebra.com/export/'+datafeedid+'/v12/branch', {
  'method': 'get',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': AuthHeader
      },
    })
  .then((httpResponse) => {
    if (httpResponse.ok) {
      //return httpResponse.json();
      console.log("Response OK: ", httpResponse);
      return (httpResponse.text());  
    } 
        })
  .then(xmlText => {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText,
                                            'text/xml');
        // Now you can work with the parsed XML document
        console.log("xmlDoc:", xmlDoc)
        return (xmlDoc);
  }
  );}
)

Branch_response.txt is the successful response from the fetch (httpResponse):
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AvYtCyRV-nEPg4sNE2lvb2OIw701Aw?e=T7EUCz
xmlDoc.txt is the xmlDoc parsed:
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AvYtCyRV-nEPg4sOqUZ9Ml4XAhAO6g?e=fvD0pf
I expect to see a readable XML with branches information as per API.

The DOM represents an XML as a tree of nodes. The nodes have references to their children, parent, ancestors and siblings. According to the error message your code is following the references and end up in circles. Most likely it expects a generic, nested JS object/array structure - not a full DOM. You can use Query Selector or Document.evaluate() to extract data from a DOM - building up a specific data structure and serialize that to JSON.

var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText,"application/xml");
solved the problem for me.
Thanks
